# How to sleep for 10 seconds using Mocha, Chai and protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, mocha.js, chai

So I have been having issue with .sleep function where it seems to skip the sleep function, The reason is that I need to manually login with username and password (Popup window) and after I have entered it manually I would like the program to continue.

Basically it is as simple as:

```js
describe('Personal information', function() {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    this.timeout(50000);

    it('enter email', function(done) {
        browser.sleep(10000).then(function() {
            console.log('waited 10 seconds');
        });

        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(piPage.enterEmail('test@test.com')), 5000);
        //enterEmail = element(by.id('email'));
    });
});
```

Basically what I want to do is that I would like to wait for 10 seconds and then in the meanwhile it should look for the element is if it presented yet. As soon as it is presented then continue the code with entering the email etc. However this code at this moment run imminently and never sleeps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that I need to call sleep on the selenium driver instance itself instead of Protractor sometimes. So this would involve using `browser.driver` instead of just `browser` like so:

```
browser.driver.sleep(10000).then(function() {
    console.log('waited 10 seconds');
});
```

Comment: Ahh that is indeed. I am trying to also figure out. browser.wait(element, 10000) doesnt seem to even wait for 10000 milliseconds either. Is that something you have also had issue with?

Comment: You need to use an expected condition or similar function in your browser.wait, not the element itself. It works by continually checking if the function returns true for the given amount of time and throws an exception if not. If your having general issues with commands being skipped though check if `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER:false` is set in your config. If it is (or you are using protractor v6+) you will need to use `async/await` syntax for all these commands

Comment: Oh right, I used example `.then(() => browser.wait(checkoutPage.getPageTitle(), 5000))` shouldn't this actually work?

Comment: This won't work because `checkoutPage.getPageTitle()` will pass the check every time as it is returning a value, You would need some form of expected condition as I mentioned in my first answer. I think you need to look into how [browser.wait](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) actually works to understand this better

Comment: Alright I think I got the browser.wait totally wrong in that case. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use an `async function`:

```
it('enter email', async function(done) {
    await browser.sleep(10000).then(function() {
        console.log('waited 10 seconds');
    });

    await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(piPage.enterEmail('test@test.com')), 5000);
    //enterEmail = element(by.id('email'));
});
```

Comment: Im getting super strange error. For some reason it says "(node:16408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined" however I do not have any isPresent anywhere at all?